# Check lowercase and uppercase search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using this query:

```
  public function autocomplete(Request $request)
   {
      $company_name = $request->input('query');
      $data = BusinessUser::where("company_name","LIKE",'%'. $company_name .'%')->pluck('company_name');
      return response()->json($data);
   }
```

In database for company name i can have this: 'Test','TEST','test'.
So how can i check all of this so that i get result. Any suggestion?

I tried this but then i get an error that i need to pass array:

```
  $data = BusinessUser::whereRaw("company_name","LIKE",'%'. $company_name .'%')->orWhereRaw("company_name","LIKE",'%'. $company_name .'%')->pluck('company_name');
```

EDIT:

I dont want to change anything in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `LOWER`:

```
BusinessUser::whereRaw('LOWER(`company_name`) like ?', ['%'.strtolower($company_name).'%'])->pluck('company_name');
```

Comment: its nice to convert company name too to lowercase using strtolower

Comment: how can i put '%' before and after because it is suggestion so i dont want to write whole name to get result...

Comment: Hmmm. What do you want? To find companies with similar names?

Comment: If the query is `BusinessUser::whereRaw('LOWER(`company_name`) like ?', [ "%" . strtolower($something_entered) . "%"])->pluck('company_name');` and a user enters `Te` he gets `Te` and `testing` as well.

Comment: i figure out ..tnx :)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin you forgot about `%` signs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer without using `whereRaw`:

```
use DB;

$data = BusinessUser::where(DB::raw('LOWER(company_name)'), 'like', '%' . strtolower($company_name) . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an encoding for `company_name` to `utf8_general_ci`. `CI` means Case-Insensitive.

Comment: i dont want to mess with database

Comment: It's hard to deal with it in php using array. If a word is 10 symbols long you have to compare your column 1024 times. Take a look at another answers - LOWER is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
$data = BusinessUser::whereRaw("company_name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE %{$company_name}%")->pluck('company_name');
```